# How to join custom table with order grid collection in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sales-order

I’m trying to join a custom table with order_grid_collection to add new column in admin sales order grid page, its working but the collection loads so slow.
how can I join this table correctly to avoid the slow loading Thanks!

```
  protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('custompayment_nestpay', 'main_table.increment_id = custompayment_nestpay.paymentID', 'card_name');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
         $this->addColumn('card_name', array(
             'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Card Name'),
             'index' => 'card_name'
         ));
….
```

Answer (score 2):

In your function the join is fine

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('custompayment_nestpay', 'main_table.increment_id = custompayment_nestpay.paymentID', 'card_name');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

You have used order increment id to join nestpay payment table, and this is the reason behind slow collection loading. If you can convert your query with entity_id then your collection will load more quickly

`increment_id` is key but not the primary key, and if you observe the table, it's data type is `varchar`, if you can populate order `entity_id` in your payment table, then you would be able to join using `entity_id`

Comment: I used increment_id because in nestpay table I have a column called paymentID which is equal to order increment_id. how can I populate entity_id in nestpay table ?

Comment: In most of the payment method, there is a form that submits on payment portal, and after return back to magento payment portal return back all the given variables, you can append entity_id in that form and use it when parameters return back from payment portal

Comment: Thank you so much Shoaib for your help, I solved it by indexing paymentID column in my custom payement table.

Comment: Great. Good to hear that you resolved your issue

Answer (score 1):

I solved the slow loading by indexing paymentID column in my custom payement table.

Comment: Good solution. +1